# How to get file details from other PCs on network

Tags: c#

I got a task to scan all PCs on our network and check whether certain image files are exists or not.

I am searching on internet but not got right track .

Is I can do this using C# (as i am comfortable with C#) console application from my server on same network? and How?

I have done this for single shared folder using below code:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();
                List<string> searchPatterns = new List<string> { "*.jpg", "*.eps", "*.gif", "*.tiff" };

                // Store a stack of our directories.
                Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();

                // Add initial directory.
                stack.Push(SharedFolderPath);

                while (stack.Count > 0)
                {
                    // Get top directory
                    string dir = stack.Pop();

                    // Add all files at this directory to the result List.
                    result.AddRange(searchPatterns.SelectMany(filter => System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter)).ToArray());

                    // Add all directories at this directory.
                    foreach (string dn in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
                    {
                        stack.Push(dn);
                    }
                }
```

I can get list of computers available on our network, but How to check how many drives are there on that remote computer? Then as Pedro has commented below, I will use $ to access all files in that drive

Comment: How is the network setup? It's likely you can completely ignore the fact that it's not a local drive. `var fi = new FileInfo(@"\\RemoteComputer\Folder");` works fine, as do mapped drives

Comment: Drives are not mapped. I have done this for shared folder. But now i have to do for all PCs in our network and scan each folder for every drive of each PC to check whether those images exist on those PCs.

Comment: you can access the disks using $ notation, i.e. \\RemoteComputer\c$ provided that you have the necessary privilieges on all those computers.

Comment: You should read [ask].

Comment: Hi Pedro, how i will come to know what drives are there on particular remote computer?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main question is just getting drive information of remote PC, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291510/remote-computer-drive-information-is-not-precise).

Comment: Thanks Orkun, I will try this and let you know.